# Can't update state with transact! in Om

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, om

In the **local-state** example in the *om-cookbook*, I'm able to update the counter using update-state! and set-state!, but not with transact!

I initialized project using chestnut template.

```
(def app-state (atom {:button-presses 0}))
```

These work

```
(defn clicks [data owner]
  (om/update-state! owner [:button-presses] inc))

(defn clicks [data owner]
  (let [value (om/get-state owner :button-presses)]
    (om/set-state! owner :button-presses (inc value))))
```

This doesn't work

```
(defn clicks [data owner]
  (om/transact! data :button-presses inc))
```

Call from IRenderState

```
om/IRenderState
    (render-state [_ state]
              (dom/div nil
                       (dom/button #js
                                   {:onClick #(clicks data owner)}
                                   "Click Moi")
                       (dom/br nil)
                       (dom/p nil
                              (str "Button Presses: " (:button-presses state)))))))
```

Comment: `transact!` is for application state and you pass it a cursor. `update-state!` and `set-state!` are for component state and you pass them the component.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing application state and a component's state. Notice how `update-state!` and `set-state!` take `owner` (the component) as argument, while `transact!` and `update!` take a [cursor](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Cursors).

```
(defn clicks [data owner]
  (om/transact! data :button-presses inc))
```

Your above example actually acts on the cursor (`data`), not the state, but your `IRenderState` implementation is looking up `:button-presses` on component's state. If you changed `(:button-presses state)` to `(:button-presses data)` everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Om Dcumentation](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Documentation), you are using transact! and passing it a function but not a function applied to the old state.
You can either do a

`(defn clicks [data owner]
      (om/transact! data :button-presses #(apply inc %))`

or simply `(partial inc)` which will expect the value to be passed in.

Also as a side note, the only difference between transact! and update! is that update! disregards the arguments (the old value of the cursor)